# Error: Invalid preproccessing directive #i did you mean #if?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks, directive

## Error: Invalid preproccessing directive #i did you mean #if?

I am learning CPP and got this error whilst using CodeBlocks IDLE.
It will not run.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
// using  switch statements
using namespace std;

const float fac = 2.54;
float x , in,cm;
char ch = 0;

int main(){

switch (ch) {
case 'i':
    in=x;
    cm=x/fac;
    break;
case 'c':
    in = x/fac;
    cm =x;
    break;
default:
    in=cm=0;
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: Can't [reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/w7wMsa). Do you have a space after `#i` on the first line? Like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/gTDMPd)?

Comment: I copy-pasted your code into my IDE but couldn't reproduce the error. Is there something missing? Have you saved the file? What's the full error message?

Comment: Try deleting the line `#include <iostream>` and retyping it. I suspect you have a non-visible character between the `i` and the `n`.

Comment: Based on the error, it looks like you've somehow msnaged to insert a non printable control character in the first line after i. Try to rewrite that line.

Comment: i ran it agian using g++ from the command line outside of codeblocks and it says ```cpp
 error: stray '`' in program``` . I figure to remove the backticks ,and replaced it wil ' ,but i still want to know why the backticks are the problem.

Comment: No, they shouldn't.

Comment: It was fowards ticks it used

Answer (score 1):

Simply copy paste from this page back to your IDE. My CodeBlocks executes this with no errors.
I don't have sufficient privileges to comment.